# A definite integral related to hypergeometric function

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I obtained the following integral when looking for a probability density function:
$$\int_0^1 x^{\alpha-1} \,(1-x) ^{-A}\, {}_2F_1 (1-A, \alpha -1-A, \alpha -A, x) \,dx$$ 
Can anyone please give me some hints of evaluating the value of the integral?

Comment: You should tell us what is known about $\alpha$ and $A$. Are they positive? In a given range?

Comment: Yes. $A$ and $\alpha$ are both positive.

Comment: you will also need A<1 to make the integral converge

Answer (score 1):

If $\Re(A)<1$ and $\Re(\alpha)>0$ *Mathematica* gives:

$$\int_0^1 \mbox{ }x^{\alpha-1} \,(1-x) ^{-A}\, {}_2F_1 (1-A, \alpha -1-A; \alpha -A; x) \mbox{ }dx$$
$$\mbox{     }=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(1-A)}{\Gamma(1+\alpha-A)}\mbox{   }
\mbox{}_3F_2(\alpha,1-A,\alpha-A-1;\alpha-A,1+\alpha-A;1)$$

Comment: This is what you get by integrating termwise, using the beta integral.

Comment: @IraGessel By termwise, I assume you mean "integrating the hypergeometric series termwise"?!

Comment: Yes, I mean integrating $x^{\alpha -1}(1-x)^{-A}$ times each term of the hypergeometric series.